# Problemas com Git

Tags: git

Estou configurando um servidor central para os repositórios, porém estou com dificuldades para fazer o **commit**. Estou seguindo esse tutorial:

**http://rberaldo.com.br/git-criando-repositorios-remotos/**

Mas quando vou fazer o `git push origin master`, ele pede a senha, informo a senha e logo retorna essa mensagem:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 223 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository 
database ./objects
remote: fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To ssh://dpsystems@192.168.0.107/home/Git_Central/Git_Elohim
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://dpsystems@192.168.0.107/home/Git_Central/Git_Elohim'
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Veja se isto te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6448242/540552

Comment: Acho que falta permissão para o usuário alterar a pasta no linux